# Attach index from list to a list of lists to create pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, indexing

I was wondering if it was possible to create a dataframe from a list of lists, where each item in the index_list is attached as an index to each value in lst:

```
index_list = ['phase1', 'phase2', 'phase3']
lst = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j']]
```

[image]

Thank you for any help!!

Edit: the inner lists are not necessarily the same size.

Comment: Looks like this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/62284286/12416453

Comment: Is it always the inner sublists are of the same size?

Comment: Not quite, as that is an issue with nested arrays, whereas I have here a list and a list of lists separately.

Comment: No, the inner sublists may be different sizes. I will update the question to reflect this, thank you

Comment: No problem. I'm glad the question is now more clear. Posted an answer too which works different sized sublists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) here.

```
pd.Series(lst,index=index_list).explode()
phase1    a
phase1    b
phase1    c
phase2    d
phase2    e
phase2    f
phase2    g
phase3    h
phase3    i
phase3    j
dtype: object
```

Another solution using [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
r_len = [len(r) for r in lst]
pd.Series(np.concatenate(lst), index=np.repeat(index_list,r_len))

phase1    a
phase1    b
phase1    c
phase2    d
phase2    e
phase2    f
phase2    g
phase3    h
phase3    i
phase3    j
dtype: object
```

Timeit results:

```
In [501]: %%timeit
     ...: pd.Series(lst,index=index_list).explode()
     ...:
     ...:
363 µs ± 16.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [503]: %%timeit
     ...: r_len = [len(r) for r in lst]
     ...: pd.Series(np.concatenate(lst), index=np.repeat(index_list,r_len))
     ...:
     ...:
236 µs ± 17.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem looks similar to R's `expand.grid()` function and is listed in [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html) **pandas cookbook** (bottom of the page).
This function lets you to create dataframe with all combinations of the given input values.

First define a function:

```
def expand_grid(data_dict):
rows = itertools.product(*data_dict.values())
return pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=data_dict.keys())
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
df = expand_grid({'index': ['phase1', 'phase2', 'phase3'],
'Col1': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j']]})
```