# Iterate over pandas dataframe columns containing nested arrays (reformulated request)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I Hope you can help. few weeks ago you did gave an huge help with a similar issue regarding nested arrays.
Today I've similar issue, and I've tried all solution you provided in this link below,

[Iterate over pandas dataframe columns containing nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62284286/iterate-over-pandas-dataframe-columns-containing-nested-arrays)

My data is an ORB vector containing description points. It returns a list. When I convert the List into an array I get this output

```
data=np.asarray([['Test /file0090',
    np.asarray([[ 84,  55, 189],
                [248, 100,  18],
                [ 68, 0,  88]])],
    ['aa file6565',
    np.asarray([[ 86,  58, 189],
                [24, 10,  118],
                [ 68, 11,  0]])],
   ['aa filejjhgjgj',
                None],
   ['Test /file0088',  
    np.asarray([[ 54,  58, 787],
                [  4,  1,  18 ],
                [  8,  1,  0 ]])]])
```

This a small sample,  real data is a array with 800.000 x 2
Some images do not return any Descriptor Points, and the value shows' None

Below an example, I've just selected 2 rows where values where "None",

```
array([['/00cbbc837d340fa163d11e169fbdb952.jpg',
        None],
       ['/078b35be31e8ac99b0cbb817dab4c23f.jpg',
        None]], dtype=object)
```

Once again, I need to get this in nx4 (in this case we have 4 variables but my real data there are 33 variables) this kind :

```
col0,             Col1,  Col2,   col3,  
Test /file0090     84,     55,    189
Test /file0090     248,   100,     18
Test /file0090     84,     55,    189
'aa file6565'      86,     58,    189
'aa file6565'      24,     10,    118
'aa file6565'      68,     11,      0
'aa filejjhgjgj'    0       0       0
'Test /file0088    54,     58,    787
'Test /file0088     4,      1,     18
'Test /file0088     8,      1,      0
```

The issue with the solution provided in the link, is when we have this "None" values in the array it returns

```
ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')
```

If someone can help me to go trought this

Comment: What is the desired output for the rows with `None`?  Do you just want to drop them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify @anky answer to handle null values by using `df.fillna('')`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).add_prefix('col')
df = df.fillna('').explode('col1').reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('col1').tolist()).add_prefix('Col')).fillna(0)
```

Returns

```
           col0   Col0   Col1   Col2
 Test /file0090   84.0   55.0  189.0
 Test /file0090  248.0  100.0   18.0
 Test /file0090   68.0    0.0   88.0
    aa file6565   86.0   58.0  189.0
    aa file6565   24.0   10.0  118.0
    aa file6565   68.0   11.0    0.0
 aa filejjhgjgj    0.0    0.0    0.0
 Test /file0088   54.0   58.0  787.0
 Test /file0088    4.0    1.0   18.0
 Test /file0088    8.0    1.0    0.0
```